# Edit Drupal Commerce Confirmation Email

Tags: emails, commerce

I've been searching everywhere but i do not know how to edit the confirmation email sent when the checkout process is complete.

Where can I edit this?

Answer (score 2):

Its in rules

admin > config >  workflow > rules

Comment: The rules don't allow you to edit the information in the email. Apparently I have to download a module to change the standard confirmation email

Comment: Um, yes you can modify exactly everything in the email. Note there are two different rules. One for admin email and one for the user email. Note I also use the commerce email module. It gives you a nice wysiwyg for editing the emails as well as a few more tokens for use in your email.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use this module https://drupal.org/project/commerce_invoice_receipt and then its very easy to modify what gets sent out.

From README:

1. Drop the 'commerce_invoice_receipt' folder into the modules directory
   '/sites/all/modules/'.
2. In your Drupal site, enable the module under Administration -> Modules
   '?q=/admin/modules'.
3. Setup new Commerce Order display under Store -> Configuration -> Order
   Settings -> Manage Display '?q=admin/commerce/config/order/display'. Click
   on the 'Invoice/Receipt' tab. Unhide any fields you want to use in your
   invoice.
4. Setup a rule under Store -> Configuration -> Checkout settings -> Checkout
   rules '?q=admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules'. Then 'Add a checkout rule',
   you'll find an action called 'Send invoice receipt email' under Commerce
   Order that you can use.

You can customize the rule to send out any info you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Using Kickstart] you can also find the raw text and tokens for messages here:

/admin/structure/messages

Answer (score 0):

install this module
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message
it will proivde access many type of messages along with their rules.
You can configure and add your own message types